# c++ - arbitrary void* chunk to bitset

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

Suppose I have a method that receives a buffer of fixed lenght, like this:

```
#define SIGN_SIZE 64

bitset<SIGN_SIZE> chunkToBitset(void * chunk);
```

Now, what I want is to create a bitset from the bits of that chunk of data (the size of the chunks is always 128 bits [16 bytes]) limited by 
`SIGN_SIZE`, where `SIGN_SIZE` can be any value in (32, 64, 96 or 128).

I tried to cast the chunk to unsigned long, but It does not seems to return the right value.
Example:

```
unsigned long ulon = (unsigned long)* chunk;
bitset<SIGN_SIZE> bs(ulon);
```

And this approach could only work when SIGN_SIZE is 64, if it is 96 it does not work.

How can I construct the bitset with all the bits in `chunk` but respecting the limit `SIGN_SIZE`? Preferably not setting bit per bit.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Loop over the data as an array of bytes, say (or `int32_t`s. or any other fixed bit size units); extract individual bits using bitwise operations; set these bits into `bitset` one by one. There's really no shortcut for bitset sizes larger than `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Your assignment of ulon sets it to the value of *the pointer*, not the value the pointer points to.

Comment: If `chunk` is a `char` array then `(unsigned long)*chunk` only reads the first byte of the array. You're probably looking for `*(unsigned long*)chunk`.